# "before all" hook: prepare suite

Tags: solidity, truffle, error

This is the error code:
[image]

Adoption.sol code:
[image]

TestAdoption.sol code:
[image]

I dont know how to solve this, it fails when i try to use this comand: "truffle test".
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`npm uninstall -g truffle`

`npm install -g truffle@5.1.10` (always got me back on track)

Comment: THIS solves my problem! Thank you very much! I also have similar "before hook", "after each" errors when using Truffle Test. Change the Truffle version to 5.1.10 solves the issues.

Answer (score 1):

delete everything inside your build folder in your truffle root project.
and then repeat

```
truffle compile
truffle migrate
truffle test
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Which truffle version are you using? I had same issue and I was using v5.1.15, the latest version for now. And I try an old v5.1.10 and it works. It's due to a compilation OS-compatibility path issue. Here you can find an article about it:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2834#issuecomment-588321875

Answer (score 0):

uninstall and install truffle helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Also, this issue occurs when used *several* test suites that use async test-helpers without **await** (for example, [OpenZeppelin Test Helpers: expectEvent, expectRevert](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api)).

Consider example:

*contract*

```csharp
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract Test03 {
    address public owner;
    int32 public id;

    event ContractCreated();

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;

        emit ContractCreated();
    }

    function doSmth(int32 _id) public {
        require(id != 0, "id is zero");
        id= _id;
    }
}
```

*test*

```js
const { expectEvent, expectRevert } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

const TestContract = artifacts.require('Test03');

contract('Test03', function (accounts) {
    const [owner] = accounts;
    const txParams = { from: owner };

    beforeEach(async function () {
        this.testContract = await TestContract.new(txParams);
    });

    describe('construction', function () {
        it('initial state', async function () {
            expect(await this.testContract.owner()).to.equal(owner);

            // !! DONT FORGET await before expectEvent-call <<------------------------------
            await expectEvent.inConstruction(this.testContract, 'ContractCreated');
        });
    });

    describe('doSmth', function () {
      it('fail when passed zero id', async function () {

        // !! DONT FORGET await before expectRevert-call <<------------------------------
        await expectRevert(
          this.testContract.doSmth(0, txParams),
          "id is zero");
      });
  });    
});
```

*package.json*

```json
{
..
  "devDependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.10"
  }
..
}
```